# Boolean expressions + short-circuit

Tags: c, debugging

I want to print a message with Boolean expressions + short-circuit evaluation (i am not allowed to use if/while/for ) but in C-Lion everything works fine but in other compiler it says:

```
hw2q1.c: In function 'decision':
hw2q1.c:38:55: error: value computed is not used [-Werror=unused-value]
|
^
S
```

> how can i solve this warning ?

I tried in C-Lion but no problem seems to appear.

```
void decision(int DragonA,int DragonB,int DragonC) {

         (DragonA == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('A') )   ||
         (DragonB == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('B') )   ||
         (DragonC == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('C') )   ||
         (print_no_dragon());
}
```

Comment: You are computing a boolean value with your expression, but you do not use it. Given that the expression has side-effects, I am not sure if it should be classified as an _error_, but at least it is worth a warning.

Comment: I guess if you only interested in the side-effects but not the value of the whole expression, you can silence the warning by casting the whole thing into `void`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie how can i solve this warning ?

Comment: EugeneSh gave you the solution.  Cast the entire expression to `void`.

Comment: Do as @EugeneSh. suggests: cast to void, i.e. `(void) ((Dra....)`

Comment: It's quite difficult to interpret where in the code that error has appeared.  It says line 38 at column 55, but as you don't publish your full code, that info is of no sense for us.  Have you written `||` as `| |` or simply `|` somewhere? the token `|` pointed to by the error message doesn't appear in your code snippet.  Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to ask here.  BTW, what you post is not a warning... but an error, as warnings are tagged as such in the compiler output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is basically fine.  I would expect a conforming C compiler to accept it.

It appears, however, that you are using compiler options that reject code that elicits a diagnostic of any kind, even one that would normally be a mere non-fatal warning.  The particular problem it is diagnosing is that you compute a value and then let it go unused.  C allows that, but sometimes it arises by mistake, and hence may warrant a warning.

Compilers that warn about that particular issue can often be satisfied by casting the value in question to type `void`.  This can be viewed as telling the compiler that you really do mean to ignore the value.  For example:

```
    (void) (
        (DragonA == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('A')) ||
        (DragonB == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('B')) ||
        (DragonC == 1 && print_dragonX_sent('C')) ||
        print_no_dragon()
    );
```