# using boolean expressions instead of if/else or similar condition

Tags: c, boolean-expression

I need to use boolen expressions instead of using terms such as: c: b? A, switch, else ... if. and using for / while-do / while as if is also not allowed.

My question is when receiving a name, based on its value we decide what to print. For example, if the name is shorter than 6 letters we print "player A is sent", if the letters sum (in ascii values) is more than 20 we send player B and stuff like that. In addition, if we can send more than one player, we will choose to send the largest lexicographic player (playerC < playerB < playerA.)

what I tried to do is something like this

```
  bool sum = AsciiSum(name)>=20;
  bool len = NameLength(name)<6;
...
```

so the rest should be that

```
if(sum) 
  printf("%c\n" ,'playerA');
else if (len) 
  printf("%c\n" ,'playerB');
else 
  printf("%c\n" ,'no player was sent');
```

But as I said , I cant use if and else or similar conditions. Will be grateful for any help in that last part.

Comment: Can you use a ternary conditional operator (`sum ? "playerA" : len ? "playerB" : "no player was sent"`)?

Comment: `AsciiSum(name)>=20 && puts("player A");` on a line by itself. Example: https://ideone.com/tsizHJ

Comment: nope. we cant @Frontear

Comment: Get some inspiration from [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537295/boolean-expressions-short-circuit)

Comment: If you use `int` instead of `bool` you can use the `0` or `1` result to index some 2-element arrays of messages.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use multi-character literal constants?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to reroute your input through a custom print function which return a boolean value. That was, you could then just use the AND (&&) operator to call it.

Example code:

```
bool printMessage(char* string)
{
    printf("%s", string);
    return true;
}

bool sum = AsciiSum(name)>=20 && printMessage("playerA");
bool len = NameLength(name)<6 && printMessage("playerB");
// ... etc
```

Why does this work? The AND operator will only allow the next condition to be checked if the first one was true. Since your condition is that sum must be true in order to print the message, this is a way to call the method to print without directly using any if/else statements

Edit: An even better way, as suggested by [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619597/using-boolen-expressions-instead-of-if-else-or-similar-condition/55619804#comment97932518_55619597) is to use stdio puts(), which returns an integer (that's what a boolean is functionally).

```
bool sum = AsciiSum(name)>=20 && puts("playerA");
bool len = NameLength(name)<6 && puts("playerB");
```

With this, you don't even have to create a `printMessage` function, though you should stay with whichever feels more comfortable to work with.

Comment: Wow that's smart.

Comment: Or, if the addition of a `'\n'` is unwanted `fputs ("playerA", stdout);`

Comment: This does not apply the if/else-if/else semantics. If both len and sum are true, both messages will be output.   `len = !sum && NameLength(name)<6 && puts("playerB");` then `!sum && !len && puts("no player");`.  There is a simpler solution however.

Comment: `puts()` returns an undefined "non-negative integer" on success - that could include zero, in which case it would be `false`.  In my test it happened to work, but I don't think it is guaranteed.  As it happens in this case it makes no difference because the RHS of the `&&` will be evaluated and the value is not used because of the issue in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given an output function that always returns `true` :

```
bool print( const char* msg )
{
    puts( msg ) ;
    return true ;
}
```

You can then exploit short-circuit evaluation thus:

```
bool sum = AsciiSum(name)>=20;
bool len = NameLength(name)<6;

(sum && print("playerA")) || 
(len && print("playerB")) || 
print("no player was sent") ;
```

Testing all combinations thus:

```
bool sum = false, len = false ;
(sum && print("playerA")) || (len && print("playerB")) || print("no player was sent") ;

sum = false, len = true ;
(sum && print("playerA")) || (len && print("playerB")) || print("no player was sent") ;

sum = true, len = false ;
(sum && print("playerA")) || (len && print("playerB")) || print("no player was sent") ;

sum = true, len = true ;
(sum && print("playerA")) || (len && print("playerB")) || print("no player was sent") ;
```

correctly outputs:

```
no player was sent                                                                                                                                       
playerB                                                                                                                                                  
playerA                                                                                                                                                  
playerA
```

Your compiler may issue a diagnostic regarding the result of the expression being unused; that can be supressed by a dummy assignment:

```
bool dummy = (sum && print("playerA")) || 
             (len && print("playerB")) ||  
             print("no player was sent") ;
```

or by casting the whole expression to void:

```
(void)((sum && print("playerA")) || 
       (len && print("playerB")) || 
       print("no player was sent")) ;
```

The only requirement of the output function is that it returns a non-zero value to short-circuit the `||`, to that end `printf()` will work if the message is not an empty string, and avoid the need to define a specific output function.:

```
(void)((sum && printf("playerA\n")) || 
       (len && printf("playerB\n")) || 
       printf("no player was sent\n")) ;
```

`puts()` however only guarantees to return a non-negative value on success, which includes zero, so should not be used.

Comment: Thank you for this explaining. but when I do that it says (value computed is not used). I tried adding void() before it but then the error would change to ( void value not ignored as it ought to be). what does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: @MaryTim The expression is not assigned because you are only interested in the side-effects.  The compiler will likely issue a warning.   Simply assign to a dummy Boolean.